# pass in popen parameters

Tags: python, subprocess

I have code like:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["/path/to/program", '-c', '-', ran_opt_get_ap], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

And I want to extract `"/path/to/program", '-c', '-'` to a variable so i can change it easily.
I have tried a few different syntax's for cmd_here and they give various errors, but what is the correct way? Here is an example I tried:

```
cmd_here = "/jffs2/usbflash0/ran/rancli -c -"
proc = subprocess.Popen([cmd_here, ran_opt_get_ap], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

This only works with `shell=True` which i wish to avoid, what syntax should I use? I had it in a list but it complained about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something that should work (untested, though):

```
constant_cmd_part = ["/path/to/program", "-opt", "-more_opt"]
proc = subprocess.Popen(constant_cmd_part + [variable_part],
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Basically, subprocess.Popen wants an initial argument that is a list of [binary, args...] and we construct one by concatenating a list of constant parts, with one with our variable part(s).

Comment: Tried this and got: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'rfind'

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `split` function to produce the appropriate list:

```
cmd_here = "/jffs2/usbflash0/ran/rancli -c -"
# split string to a list
args = cmd_here.split()
args.append(ran_opt_get_ap)
proc = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

**Result of split command:**

```
cmd_here = "/jffs2/usbflash0/ran/rancli -c -"
In [2]: cmd_here.split()
Out[2]: ['/jffs2/usbflash0/ran/rancli', '-c', '-']
```